# I can not install new react npx function for installing Packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

when I type  npx create-react-app new-app on windows Powershell , I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Shahzad\AppData\Local\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Shahzad\AppData\Local\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Shahzad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-10T16_37_25_847Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried many methods but they didn't worked.